# Locating A WiFi Network Password Within OS X That Has Been Saved On My Mac?

Tags: wifi, password

Is it possible to locate a wifi network password in OS X of a wifi hotspot that I may have used in the past (AFAIK wifi networks are saved), in the rare situation that I may need to see it (to share it for example) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have saved it previously, open `Keychain Access` (located in `/Applications/Utilities` or via Spotlight) and search for the wifi network name.

If you have found it, check the lowest checkbox to reveal the password. You need your login password to do so.

Comment: Thankyou for explaining that. What exactly is Keychain, I have never come across it before ?

Comment: Keychain Access is an application located in your Utilities folder (at /Applications/Utilities). It stores certain passwords in an encrypted fashion.

Comment: Exactly - sorry for naming it wrong. I'm using german version of OS X where it's called "Schlüsselbundverwaltung". I'll edit my post.

Comment: @KarstenS. No worries, thanks for re-editing your answer :)